# recursive function is not working as expected.

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
  public function subchapt()
  {
   $result = $this->recursive_subchapter_id($level_title);
 }

  public function recursive_subchapter_id($level_title)
 {
    $level_data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM presto_project_level WHERE level_title ='". $level_title."'")->result_array();

if(count($level_data)>0){
    $parentid1 = '';
    $leveltitle1 = '';
    $parentid1 = trim($level_data[0]['parent_id']);
    $leveltitle1 = trim($level_data[0]['level_title']);

    if($parentid1 == '0') {

       return $leveltitle1;die;
    } 
    else 
    {   
       $res = $this->recursive_subchapter_id($parentid1);
       return $res;die;
    }
}
else{
    return $level_title;die;
}
}
```

every time getting result array is null. i tried directly in url so it was give result array and its count. but while call from other function it was give count of zero.

Comment: In your function `subchapt()` where is `$level_title` set?

Comment: in subchapt() function, i have written the code to get  $level_title from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of checking the `parentid` in the `recursive_subchapter_id()`, check in `subchapt()` and then call again `recursive_subchapter_id()` if it not satisfy the condition.